# $X$ and $Y$ has uniform distribution. Find $(X-Y)^2$

Tags: uniform-distribution, density-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a independent random variable with uniform distribution on the $[-1,1]$.
Let $Z=(X-Y)^2$. Find :

1. Expected value:
   $ E(Z)=E(X^2)-2E(X)E(Y)+E(Y^2)=\frac{4}{3}$
2. Probablity density function:

Here, I have problem. I think, that I can write :

$P((X-Y)^2 \le t)$=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{for } t \le 0\\P((X-Y)\le \sqrt{t}) &\text{for } 0<t\le1 \\1&\text{for}\  t\ge1 \end{cases}
I'm not sure what to do next..

Comment: $Z$ can be as great as $4$...

Comment: Yes, You're right..

Comment: Are you assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes.I am sorry, I forgot to write about it.

Comment: Use calculus to evaluate $E(X)$,  $E(X^2)$, and so on. For part 2, look at the region in the $(x,y)$ plane cut out by the inequality $(x-y)^2\le t$ and find (by calculus or otherwise) its area.  That will lead to the cdf ; take its derivative to get the pdf.